# How to release memory in android to avoid memory leak

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks

While going through the android developer site i found this [image: it says to avoid memory leak we should release resources in onStop()].

it says to avoid memory leak we should release resources  in onStop()but how to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically any objects that are properly nulled are considered released and their memory can be reclaimed by the OS. Your question is too general and it's hard to offer a exhaustive list of methods, but you should generally be aware of these:

1. Stop/close any services/files/connections that you no longer need
2. Do NOT store any Drawable in any static Object, Drawables hold references to their owner View's which hold references to their owner Activity's, so if you hold on to any Drawable you will hold onto *a lot* of objects/memory unnecessarily
3. For an utility app, you probably needn't worry about memory; but for apps that use lots of Bitmaps, you should have a deep understanding of [Bitmap management](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) and how Bitmaps are used in your app in order to manage them effectively

Comment: So I should make all of my textviews and imagebuttons null in the `onPause`?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia there's no need for that since: a. if only onPause() is called, the Activity would be referenced by the OS. b. if onDestory() is called, then Activity and everything it references will be released anyway. It is only when some other object or some class's static variable(s) get holds of the Activity being released that a leak would occur.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few notorious examples of memory hogs, with media (audio/video) and large bitmaps being the biggest memory hogs.  Most things are taken care of by removing all pointers to them and letting GC have its way with them. Bitmaps, however, can be recycled more immediately by using:

```
if (yourBitmap != null) {
    yourBitmap.recycle();
    youBitmap = null;
}
```

Your media should be stopped and de-referenced.  But it should be stopped in onPause(), and not left until onStop().

Comment: k I can remove the reference of the Bitmap but how about objects as I am running out of memory

Comment: make sure that you .recycle() your bitmaps, not just remove the reference.  This will free your memory more quickly.  Kai left some good points in his answer.

Comment: what about drawables?

Comment: So I should make all of my textviews and imagebuttons null in the `onPause`?