# Service based app consuming high RAM on android

Tags: android, memory-management, service, ram, custom-keyboard

My app is based on InputMethodService , it is a custom keyboard app.. We are showing different tabs, images, gifs,google ads, news etc from server in this app in a service.
My app is consuming high RAM. This app is making device slow...
I am already clearing every list, arraylist after use.. ..

I tried to put my service in a different process like this

```
<service
            android:name="services.Myservice"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
            android:process=":myprocess">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/method" />
        </service>
```

It helps but then I was unable to get onclick of ads , clicking on ads was doing nothing and it was also causing few more issues ..like i was unable to update themes and all..

So, now My app is too slow in typing and it is taking huge RAM around 170-200 MB most of the time.
I used google play service for showing ads and notifications.. that is also a reason of high RAM consumption ..

But there are many apps with all these feature..how do they manage RAM?

Here is a report from MAT :

[image]

Please help me on this!!
Looking forward for suggestions!!

Comment: We can't give specifics other than general guidelines. Read this, [Investigate Ram](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways in which you can reduce memory consumption.

1. Use proguard to obfuscate the unneeded code. [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)
2. You can also use lint cleaner. this removes unused resources reported by Android lint including strings, colors and dimensions. [Link](https://github.com/marcoRS/lint-cleaner-plugin)
3. Remove external libs from gradle which are not being used.
4. Use service calls sparingly. You can give the user the option to refresh the data(if possible) whenever new data is needed.
5. Release unused xml and java resources when they are not being used, or simply release them when onDestroy() gets called. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894903/how-to-release-memory-in-android-to-avoid-memory-leak) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328745/how-to-destroy-release-resources-used-in-1-activity-layout)
6. Remember to close the cursor after querying the database. If you want to keep the cursor open long-term, you must use it carefully and close it as soon as the database task finished.
   Also, Remember to call unregisterReceiver() after calling registerReceiver(). [Link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/tips-for-optimizing-android-application-memory-usage)

Comment: then instead of continuously running the service, ask user to refresh whenever new data is available.